# hector_qrcode_detection

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't to start work with hector_qrcode_detection. I edited [this](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision/blob/master/hector_qrcode_detection/launch/qrcode_detection.launch) launch file I only change this sector

```
<remap from="openni/image"             to="/image_raw" />
<remap from="openni/image_percept"     to="worldmodel/image_percept" />
<remap from="openni/image/qrcode"      to="image/qrcode" />
<remap from="openni/image/camera_info" to="/camera_info" />
```

Because I use uvc_camera for testing, but I going to use this package with kinect. So when I start this launch file, I didn't see that any topic supsribes to image_raw. Where is problem? What I'm doing wrong?

rostopic info /image_raw

```
Type: sensor_msgs/Image

Publishers: 
 * /uvc_camera (http://turtle-comp:34051/)

Subscribers: None
```

rostopic list | grep image

```
/image_raw
/image_raw/compressed
/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/image_raw/compressedDepth
/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/image_raw/theora
/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
```

rosnode list

```
/qrcode_detection_kinect
/qrcode_detection_pseye_left
/qrcode_detection_pseye_right
/rosout
/uvc_camera
```

rosnode info /qrcode_detection_kinect

```
Node [/qrcode_detection_]
Publications: None

Subscriptions: None

Services: None
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156581/hector_qrcode_detection/) by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, camera nodes publish their topics (image_raw, camera_info etc.) to a sub namespace (/camera/image_raw, /camera/camera_info etc.) as opposed directly to the root namespace. Note also that the example launch file uses nodelets, and loads the qr detection nodelets into already pre-existing camera nodelet managers. It would help if you can edit your original question and post the output of the following commands:

```
rostopic info /image_raw
```

- 

```
 rostopic list | grep image
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on 2014-04-23**:
I edited question with outputs. I hope it helps. Honestly I don't know a lot about nodelets, but I'll of course read about it.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-24**:
Ok, looks like the qr code detection node might not be running. What's the output of "rosnode list"?

**Comment by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on 2014-04-26**:
I added output rosnode list and output rosnode info /qrcode_detection_kinect. But how we can see the node is runnig, but it doesn't have any subscribers or publisher.